Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi}\sin(2nx)/\sin(x)\,dx$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$
I'm studying for the math subject GRE and this question was on a practice test. I will restate the question, then provide my solution.
Solve the following integral: $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(100x)}{\sin(x)}dx$
Here is my solution. Let $M = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(100x)}{\sin(x)}dx$
Let $x=\pi - u$ so that $dx = -du$. Then the integral becomes $$\begin{align}M &= \int_\pi^0 \frac{\sin(100(\pi-u))}{\sin(\pi-u)}(-du) \\ &= \int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(100\pi -100u)}{\sin(\pi - u)}du \\ &= \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(-100u)}{\sin(u)} \\ &= -\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(100u)}{\sin(u)}du \\ &= -M\end{align}$$
Using the fact that $u\in [0,\pi]$ so that $\sin(\pi - u) = \sin(u)$. But then $M = -M$ implies that $M = 0$, which is indeed the correct solution.
My complaint is that I do not like this solution, as I feel like the replacement of $x$ with $\pi - u$ is very unintuitive and I wouldn't have been able to see this during the exam. Does anybody have another way to think about the problem? Thank you.

Maybe this is more familiar if you use $\int_0^\pi = \int_0^{\pi/2} + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi$ and apply what amounts to the same change of variables in the second integral (to get the $(0,\epsilon)$ part of the first to cancel the (\pi - \epsilon, \pi)$ part of the second).

The substitution $x\to\pi-x$ is actually intuitive, even one property of definite integrals is based on this: $$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\mathrm dx$$

Hint: expand
$$\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos((2k+1)x)\right)\cdot \sin(x)$$
This allows you to trade one integral for fifty; is that a good trade?
